# Object not passed into method from JSON body

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I'm attempting to run a method I've created in an MVC API which requires an object to be passed into it via the body in JSON format. As far as I'm aware there's no errors with the method or the object, but the JSON that I'm sending is not actually passed into the method and the object parameter remains null.

This is the method:

```
 // Consignment Search
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Legacy.JobTracking))]
[Route("api/search/")]
public IHttpActionResult SearchConsignment(ConsignmentSearch search)
{ 
    // Get the ID
    var UserId = 0;
    using (_PortalDb)
    {
        var User = _PortalDb.PortalUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ServerUser == search.User);
        if (User != null) UserId = User.UserId;
    }
    List<Legacy.JobTracking> Consignments;
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Invalid Search");
    if (search.JobNo == null && search.CustRef == null && search.ConRef == null && search.DateFrom == null && search.DateTo == null) return BadRequest("No search filters");
    if (search.JobNo != null)
    {
        // Run Job number search and continue
        Consignments = Legacy.Exporter.GetJobByNo(search.JobNo, search.User, search.Account, UserId);
    }
    else if (search.ConRef != null)
    {
        // Run Con Ref Search and continue
        Consignments = Legacy.Exporter.GetJobByCon(search.ConRef, search.User, search.Account, UserId);
    }
    else if (search.CustRef != null)
    {
        // Run Customer Ref Search and continue
        Consignments = Legacy.Exporter.GetJobByRef(search.CustRef, search.User, search.Account, UserId);
    }
    else if (search.DateFrom != null && search.DateTo != null)
    {
        // Run Date Range Search and continue
        Consignments = Legacy.Exporter.GetJobsInDateRange(search.DateTo, search.DateFrom, search.User, search.Account, UserId);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid Date Search");
    }
    return Ok(Consignments);
}
```

The class:

```
public class ConsignmentSearch
{
    public string JobNo;
    public string CustRef;
    public string ConRef;
    public string DateFrom;
    public string DateTo;
    public string User;
    public string Account;
}
```

And the JSON in the body:

```
["consignmentSearch": {
  "dateFrom": "20150101",
  "dateTo": 20160101,
  "user": "LianeS",
  "account": "PORTAL"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text that you pass in body of your request is not valid JSON (and of course does not represent your model also). Valid JSON for your case will be something like:

```
{
  "dateFrom": "20150101",
  "dateTo": 20160101,
  "user": "LianeS",
  "account": "PORTAL"
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!